# JQuery - siblings based on next()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

Siblings based on `next()`, but looks like it is still based on the selector before next function, so I used `next()` for siblings, but not working. The section commented out is working in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BillD/vt5y0u9r/1/), anyone can figure it out the second JS code? Thanks!

```
$('.touch').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle().siblings().next().hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Is this what you were trying to do? `$(this).parent().next().toggle().siblings().next().hide();`?

Comment: Please comment out  JS part  in JSFiddle to view its aim.

Answer (score 0):

next() refers to the next child of the parent, so next has to be applied to the parent element. So you would do something like this to grab the next sibling.

```
 $(this).parent().next()....
```